# Convert .xls file to .xlsx format in SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, excel, pnp-powershell, automation

I have .xls files (Eg: Book.xls) available in my SharePoint Online folder (https://.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/Book.xls").

I want to convert them to .xlsx format (Eg: Book.xlsx) in the same location using PowerShell.

Can someone help with this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to convert .xls file to .xlsx file in sharepoint

```
 Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

# Input parameters for the script
$xlWorkbookDefault = 51
$xlExcel8 = 56
$xlFixedFormat = $xlWorkbookDefault


#$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::$xlExcel8


$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false


$websiteurl = read-host "Enter site URL"
$web = Get-SPWeb $websiteurl

$LibraryName = read-host "Enter Library Name"

Function CopyMetadata($MetaFile)
{

$searchfile = $MetaFile.file
$searchfileurl = $searchfile.Url
$searchfilename = $searchfileurl+"x"

$folder = $web.GetFolder($LibraryName)
$library = $folder.DocumentLibrary
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$spQuery.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>.xls</Value></Contains></Where>";
$listItems = $library.GetItems($spQuery)
$targetfileItem = $MetaFile
foreach($item in $listItems)
{
$sourcefile = $item.file
$sourcefileurl = $sourcefile.Url

if($sourcefileurl -eq $searchfilename)
{

$item["Author"] = $targetfileItem["Author"]
$item["Editor"] = $targetfileItem["Editor"]
$item["Created"] = $targetfileItem["Created"]
$item["Modified"] = $targetfileItem["Modified"]
$item.Update()
$searchfile.Delete()
}
}

}
Function getallfiles($test)
{
write-host "copying Metadata information and deleting Original File"

$folder = $web.GetFolder($LibraryName)
$library = $folder.DocumentLibrary
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$spQuery.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>.xls</Value></Contains></Where>";

$listItems = $library.GetItems($spQuery)

foreach($item in $listItems)
{
$filename = $item.file
$inputFile = $filename.name
$fileextension = $inputFile.substring($inputFile.lastindexof('.'),($inputFile.length - $inputFile.lastindexof('.')))
if($fileextension -eq ".xls")
{
CopyMetadata($item)

}
}

}

Function ProcessFolder([string]$folder)
 {
write-host "conversion job started"
$inputFolder = $web.GetFolder($folder)
$library = $inputFolder.DocumentLibrary
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$spQuery.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='File'>.xls</Value></Contains></Where>";

$listItems = $library.GetItems($spQuery)
foreach ($item in $listItems)
{
$fileobj = $item.file
$fileurl = $fileobj.Url
$inputFile = $fileobj.name
$fileextension = $inputFile.substring($inputFile.lastindexof('.'),($inputFile.length - $inputFile.lastindexof('.')))
if($fileextension -eq ".xls")
{

$outputFile = $inputFile.Replace(".xls",".xlsx")
$inputfileurl = $web.Url+"/"+$fileurl
$outputfileurl = $inputfileurl.Replace(".xls",".xlsx")
#Add input and output folders and start conversion
try
{
write-host -Fore Green "converting file :     $inputfileurl"
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($inputfileurl)
$workbook.saveas($outputfileurl, $xlFixedFormat)
$workbook.save()  
$workbook.close()
}
catch [system.exception]
{
   #Write-host "Exception occured while converting file : $($_.Exception.Message)"
write-host -Fore Red "File failed to convert : $inputfileurl"
   #do some error handling
}
catch
{
Write-error -Fore Red "Error occured while converting file $inputFile"
}


}

}

}
ProcessFolder($LibraryName)
$excel.displayalerts = $False
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
getallfiles("welcome")
write-host "Conversion operation complete "
$web.Dispose()
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @RaytheonXie-MSFT . If I run this code, I'm getting the following error.
'Add-PsSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand'

Comment: So I executed 'Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell' command and tried executing your code again and it shows the URL and expecting the input and If I enter anything and click enter, it shows the Library Name and expecting the input again. I'm not very sure what to enter when I asked for inputs. I'm very new to this, can you please help me with step by step.

Thanks.

Comment: "Enter site URL" needs the sharepoint site url like "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/test".             "Enter Library Name" needs the name of library which have xls file to convert